# AES GCM/CTR same output

Tags: c++, c, encryption, openssl, aes

I'm trying to use AES-GCM. My code for encryption works, but when I try to encrypt the same plain text with the same IV and key, I've got same result. My code for GCM:

```
EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
int outlen, tmplen;
unsigned char outbuf[1024];
ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_gcm(), NULL, NULL, NULL);
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_SET_IVLEN, sizeof(gcm_iv), NULL);
EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, NULL, NULL, gcm_key, gcm_iv);
EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, NULL, &outlen, gcm_aad, sizeof(gcm_aad));
EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, outbuf, &outlen, gcm_pt, sizeof(gcm_pt));
printf("Ciphertext:\n");
BIO_dump_fp(stdout, outbuf, outlen);
EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, outbuf, &outlen);
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_GET_TAG, 16, outbuf);

printf("\n\n\n");

EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_gcm(), NULL, NULL, NULL);
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_SET_IVLEN, sizeof(gcm_iv), NULL);
EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, NULL, NULL, gcm_key, gcm_iv);
EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, NULL, &outlen, gcm_aad, sizeof(gcm_aad));
EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, outbuf2, &outlen2, gcm_pt, sizeof(gcm_pt));
printf("Ciphertext:\n");
BIO_dump_fp(stdout, outbuf2, outlen2);
EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, outbuf2, &outlen2);
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_GET_TAG, 16, outbuf2);
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
```

If in the second encryption I will remove init_ex, ctx_ctrl etc, my ciphertext will be an empty string.

But if I will use EVP_aes_256_ctr, then next encryption will give me new ciphertext. Code for EVP_aes_256_ctr:

```
EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
int outlen, tmplen;
unsigned char outbuf[1024];
ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_ctr(), NULL, NULL, NULL);
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_SET_IVLEN, sizeof(gcm_iv), NULL);
EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, NULL, NULL, gcm_key, gcm_iv);
EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, outbuf, &outlen, gcm_pt, sizeof(gcm_pt));
BIO_dump_fp(stdout, outbuf, outlen);
EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, outbuf, &outlen);

printf("\n\n\n");

EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, outbuf, &outlen, gcm_pt, sizeof(gcm_pt));
printf("Ciphertext:\n");
BIO_dump_fp(stdout, outbuf, outlen);
EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, outbuf, &outlen);
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
```

As I understood both modes work in Counter mode, so the counter will make different cyphers for same IV,Key,Plaintext. So why in GCM mode cyphertext is the same?

Comment: Why wouldn’t you expect encrypting the same plaintext with the same key and IV to produce the same value?  Did you want to repeat the plaintext as the second block?

Comment: Yes. I expect that data can repeat. And as I understood for my security wouldn't be broken the cipher must be different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the algorithm twice with the same inputs, you’ll get the same outputs.  If you want to encrypt the same plaintext multiple times and not let an attacker see it’s the same, use a different IV.  If you want to repeat a block within the plaintext and not let an attacker deduce the pattern, you don’t want to restart.  Notice how, in the example that worked, you called `EVP_EncryptInit_ex()` *before* your calls to `EVP_EncryptUpdate()`, and in the example that didn’t, you called `EVP_EncryptInit_ex()` again *between* them.

Comment: Ok, I removed "EVP_EncryptInit_ex" and "EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl" lines. But result is the same.
So I need to encrypt my packetized data. As I understood, I can use EVP_aes_256_ctr to do what I want or use GCM but for each packet set the new IV?

Comment: Call `EVP_EncryptUpdate()` multiple times after initializing the `ctx` once. Some example code: https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption#Authenticated_Decryption_using_GCM_mode

Comment: So I should use it without verifying the tag? EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_GET_TAG, 16, outbuf) called after encrypt_final

Comment: You should verify the tag when decrypting.  Call `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_AEAD_SET_TAG, taglen, tag);` after `EVP_EncryptInit_ex()` but before `EVP_DecryptUpdate()`.